# Fatal error: Call to a member function Show_LastRec_Pack() on a non-object

Tags: function, php

It has been already 5 days and still can't figure out where's the problem! so here i post the error and the whole code. Hopefully someone can help! I'll appreciate it very much.

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function Show_LastRec_Pack() on a non-object in packgames.php on line 69
```

here's "packgames.php":

```
<?
/**
 * Block Last Rec Pack
 **/
define ('PACK_GAMES_TO_SHOW', 3);

require_once ('recmod/constants.php');

$query = "SELECT r.*, pp.topic_id, p.Nick, b.*, p.Rating
            FROM " . TABLE_RECGAMES . " r,  " . $this->db->obj['sql_tbl_prefix'] . "attachments a, " . $this->db->obj['sql_tbl_prefix'] . "posts pp,
                " . TABLE_PLAYERS." p, recs_aoc_flags b
            WHERE a.attach_id = r.attach_id 
                AND a.attach_rel_id = pp.pid 
                AND r.Id_Player > 0
                AND p.Id_Player = r.Id_Player
                AND b.flag_id = p.flag_id
            ORDER BY r.Id_RecordedGame DESC
            LIMIT " . PACK_GAMES_TO_SHOW;

$this->DB->query($query);       
$packs = array ();
while ($player = $this->DB->fetch ())
{
    $flag = '<img src="' . PATH_FLAGS . $player['flag_image'] . '" alt="'.$player['flag_country'].'" title="' . $player['flag_country'] . '" align="absmiddle" border="0">';

    $packs[] = array (
      'GAMES' => $player['Players'],
      'PLAYER' => $player['Nick'],
      'FLAG' => $flag,
      'RATING' => $player['Rating'],
      'ID_POST' => $player['topic_id']
    );
}
$tmp = $this->registry->getClass('output')->getTemplate('recgames')->Show_LastRec_Pack ($packs);    
echo $tmp;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Whatever that object call template is returning, it's not an object. Do some var_dumps() on the call chain and figure out where a null or other non-object is being returned. Most likely on `getTemplate()`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply!! I tried: echo var_dump($tmp); but to no avail ! it keeps alerting same error on this line:
$tmp = $this->registry->getClass('output')->getTemplate('recgames')->Show_LastRec_Pack ($packs);